# SharePoint 2013 FBA with custom membership and role provider

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I am trying to implement Forms based authentication (membership provider and role provider).I am following this article ( `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg317440%28v=office.14%29.aspx` ) I downloaded and re-build the solution so that it is 4.5 compatible and followed all the steps and I am able to log in using Forms users (user1,user2),eventually i am going to get this information from a sql user table and role table

```
user table       Role table  userrole table
user1            role1           user1  role1
user2            role2           user2 role2
user3            role3           user3 role1
```

let say if I have to add user4, 
can I just add user4 to user table and assign it a role in userrole table and that SharePoint would automatically be able to make the connection and I dont have to log in to SharePoint and assign the user a sharepoint role ?

If i still have to go to SharePoint and add user4 manually and assign him a role in SharePoint what is the use of implementing role provider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if these users were in AD you would still have to add them to sharepoint groups to grant them access to a site, just adding users to AD doesn't do that for you. You can add AD groups into sharepoint and then adding users to these ad groups would grant access to wherever these ad groups exist in sharepoint.

Doing this with a provider is no different. What you should try is ensuring all the users in the provider are in groups and then add those groups to sharepoint. Then any users added to these groups in the provider would have access to sharepoint wherever these groups have been added in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should grant permissions for role1, role2, role3 to SharePoint, and after you add users in DB to that roles, they should be automatically assigned in SharePoint.